# Xcode error on running app with embedded framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am trying to create framework of my existing app which can be added to any other app as a module. In previous version of the app, i don't have any issues creating the framework and adding it to a demo app to test if it works. With newer version of the app, i am having an issue:

2017-04-21 13:59:02.238333-0400 XXX[8320:3762763] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1868c2fd8 0x185324538 0x1867a4888 0x1010c3948 0x18c9f1f9c 0x18ca09a28 0x18cb8e2a0 0x18caa8c4c 0x18caa88b4 0x18caa8818 0x18c9ef158 0x189bdf274 0x189bd3de8 0x189bd3ca8 0x189b4f360 0x189b763c0 0x189b76e8c 0x1868709a0 0x18686e628 0x18686ea74 0x18679ed94 0x188208074 0x18ca57130 0x100084860 0x1857ad59c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any suggestions how to trace back the error inside the embedded framework?
It is happening only with the main View Controllers of the app, not on any off the second level View Controllers which are accessed from these main View Controllers.

I went through the code of the old version and the new version of the embedded framework, i don't see anything major to be different, checked Line by Line the whole code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the crash log.

Comment: From the exception it looks like you are inserting an object into an uninitialised array. Or inserting a nil object into an array. Would need to know what event causes the exception to occur to help further

Comment: The stack trace, doesn't show me anything, except the crash in main.

Comment: I checked the insertObject, but i don't use it anywhere that option in all code. I am not very familiar with the troubleshooting, but all i can say is that the error is from the Embedded framework i am using in the app.

Comment: Replace the .framework with the framework project (by drag & drop) in your demo app. Build the framework target first, then the demo app target. Now it should be possible to debug into the framework. Note: You have to set breakpoints in demo app and debug into framework by stepping. If i remember correctly breakpoints in framework code only works after you already debugged into the project.

Comment: Thanks for the info codealchimist. I will try to do that right now and see how it goes. If i have any questions, i will ask

Comment: ok, i thought it will be much easier and i won't have to ask for help, but it looks like it is not that easy. I added the framework project into the demo app, but now i can not import the main header file from the framework project. codealchimist any suggestions? i tried the header search path, but none of the files are being found from the framework project.

Comment: @codealchimist, can you help with the issue?

Comment: I followed solution from codealchimist, but now i am not able to find the needed classes in order to build and compile the demo app project. 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DMSAppManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you codealchimist for the solution, i figure out what i was missing in order to be able to debug it. The solution provided by him solves the problem to be able to debug the app & framework.